# How to replace pipe instead of comma in a csv file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to convert csv file from comma separated to pipe(|). But in csv file some lines should have comma also,

My file

```
$ cat a.txt
"a","b","c,test","new","abc"
```

Expecting:

```
a|b|c,test|new|abc
```

Comment: There is an odd number of double quotes and your output has a pipe where there was not a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sed` command will do:

```
sed 's/","/\|/g; s/"//g' File
```

Replace all `","` patterns with `|`. This will have `"` at either ends, which is removed later.

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ cat File
"a","b","c,test","new","abc"

AMD$ sed 's/","/\|/g; s/"//g' File
a|b|c,test|new|abc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ':cycle
s/^\(\("[^"]*"[|]\{0,1\}\)*\),/\1|/
t cycle' YourFile
```

- recursive posix version.
- A shortcut with `[|]\{0,1\}` assuming there is no `"foo"|,` or `"foo",,` (empty field are `""`)
- another assumption here, there is no double quote inside quoted string (even escaped)

Answer (score 1):

CSV can be tricky to get right by hand. I'd use a language with a proper CSV parser. For example, with ruby:

```
$ ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts CSV.generate_line(CSV.parse_line($_), :col_sep=>"|")' a.txt
a|b|c,test|new|abc
```

That loops over the lines of the file, parses it into an array using the defaults (comma separated, double quotes as the quote character), then generates a new CSV string using pipe as the separator. If a field were to contain a pipe character, that field would be quoted.

This parser cannot handle embedded newlines in a quoted field. Perl's [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) can.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'","' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1; gsub(/"/,"")} 1' a.txt
a|b|c,test|new|abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl in the following way:

```
cat a.txt | perl -ne 's/^"//; s/"$//; @items = split /","/; print join("|", @items);'
```